# C string library inspired by Python string functions

Tags: optimization, c, strings, library

I'm working on a C library which attempts to bring some of the Python string functions over to C.

[This](https://github.com/shrimpboyho/octo) is where my full source is located, but the majority of what I have so far is here.

Are there any places where code efficiency can be improved?

```
#ifndef OCTO_H
#define OCTO_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int len(char* string){

    int i = 0;
    while(*string != '\0'){
        i++;
        *string++;
    }

    return i;

}

char* lstrip(char* string){

    if(!string) 
        return;

    /* Trim off leading whitespace */
    while(*string == ' '){
        string++;
    }

    return string;

}

char* rstrip(char* string){

    /* Trim off trailing whitespace */
    char* end = string + len(string) - 1;
        while (end >= string && *end == ' ')
                end--;
        *(end + 1) = '\0';

    return string;

}

char* strip(char* string){

    /* Trim off both leading and trailing whitespace */
    char* lstring = lstrip(string);
    char* finalString = rstrip(lstring);

    return finalString;

}

char* slice(char* s, int start, int end){

    /* Create a new identical buffer */
    char* buff = (char*) malloc((end - start) + 2);
    strncpy(buff, s + start, (end - start) + 1);
    *(buff + (end - start) + 1) = '\0';
    return buff;
}

char* toUpperCase(char* s){


}

char* toLowerCase(char* s){


}

#endif /* OCTO_H */
```

Comment: It is not a header file so your multiple-inclusion barrier is unnecessary (`#ifndef OCTO_H` etc)

Comment: @WilliamMorris: Do we call these *multiple-inclusion barrier* as Header Guards?

Comment: @WedaPashi: Yes, header guards are there to prevent the header from being included more than once.

Comment: Note that the identifier `string` is reserved for the standard library, so you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 5):

Well efficiency can be improved by using the built-in string functions.
They have been optimized at the assembly level for most implementations.

Assuming you were writing len() in C rather than using some optimal assemble instructions. The canonical form looks more like this (though I am sure it can be done better). Though there is `strlen()` which does the same thing.

```
int len(char* string)
{
    char *end = string;
    for(;*end;++end)  /* Notice nothing here */;
    return end-string;
}
```

Looking at this:

```
char* lstrip(char* string){


    /* This makes it non optimal for strings we already know are good.
     * If I already know my string is fine I would want a function that
     * did not do this test.
     *
     * Of course you can then have a second function that does the test
     * then calls the non checked version (and if it is short the compiler
     * will inline
     */
    if(!string)
        /* Not returning a value from a function expecting a value is an error
         * Check the warning messages generated by the compiler
         */      
        return;

    /*
     * ' ' is not white space it is just a space character
     *    What you are looking for is isspace(c)
     */    
    while(*string == ' '){
        string++;
    }

    return string;
}
```

I would have written like this:

```
char* lstripNT(char* string){ return string?lstrip(string):NULL;}
char* lstrip(char* string){
    for(;isspace(string);++string) /*Nothing here*/;
    return string;

    // NOTE: there is an issue with this technique in that you
    //       are not returning the original string.
    //       If the string was dynamically allocated
    //       you now have issues with freeing it. Which means you
    //       specifically need to keep a copy of the original pointer
    //       for the purpose of freeing it when you are finished.
    //       This is NOT a good idea.
}
```

Because of the problem with dynamic allocation I would probably write like this:

```
char* lstrip(char* string)
{
    size_t  move = 0;
    char*   start= string;
    for(;isspace(start);++start,++move)
    {}
    if (move)
    {
        // Move all the characters down.
        // So we basically squish the white space.
        for(;*start;++start)
        {
            *(start-move) = *start;
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Right trim. Is not really optimal because you scan to the end (using len). Then you then scan backwards until you find a non space character. You can do this in a single traverse. Also you are not being consistent. lstrip() checks for NULL while this does not.

```
char* rstripNT(char* string){ return string?rstrip(string):NULL;}
char* rstrip(char* string){

      char* loop    = string;
      char* last    = NULL;
      int   isSpace = false;
      while(*loop)
      {
          isSpace = TRUE;
          last    = loop;
          for(;*loop && isspace(*loop);++loop)
          {}
          if (*loop)
          {
              isSpace = FALSE;
              for(;*loop && !isspace(*loop);++loop)
              {}
          }
      }
      if (isSpace)
      {
          *last = '\0';
      }
      return string;
}
```

The strip.

```
char* strip(char* string){

    /* Trim off both leading and trailing whitespace */
    char* lstring = lstrip(string);
    char* finalString = rstrip(lstring);

    return finalString;

}
```

This is conceptually what you want to do.
But I don't think that will be optimal way to do it. I would write this as a single pass.

Comment: I think ```for(;*end;++end)  /* Notice nothing here */;``` should be ```for(;*end;++end){}  /* Notice nothing here */;```

Comment: @Cygwinnian: Those are both the same. The standard is `for(<init>;<test>;<inc>)<statement>`. Statement can be the empty statement `;` or it can be Block `{}` both work the same way.

Comment: @LokiAstari Sorry didn't see the semicolon at the end of the comment.

Comment: To expand on the point about using built-in functions, `strlen()` in particular is likely to have an built-in implementation that is faster than you’d be able to hand code in C.

Comment: @microtherion: I though I said that in the first sentence.

Comment: @LokiAstari, yes, you did say to use built-in functions in general. My point was that `strlen()` (The simplest of them, and maybe therefore the most tempting to roll oneself) was in fact that most likely to be optimized.

Comment: @microtherion: You are correct and a point worth emphasizing.

Answer (score 4):

These points are mostly designed-oriented:

- I'd recommend having `len()` return a `size_t` with `i` as the same type.  This type is preferred for size functions and is also used in libraries.
- Although just another form, `lstrip()` can be done this way:

  ```
  char* lstrip (char* string) {

      // skip and return right away if condition is not met
      if (string) {
          /* Trim off leading whitespace */
          while (*string == ' ') {
              string++;
          }
      }

      return string;
  }
  ```

  Also, your plain `return` won't work because the function is supposed to return a `char*`.

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency is just one of the issues with your library.  Here are some other concerns.

**Implementation as a header file.**  Most libraries are linked in to the code that uses it; yours is compiled in, by being `#include`d as a header file.  What happens if `file1.c` and `file2.c` each uses `octo.h`?  Then when you try to link `file1.o` and `file2.o` together, each of your functions would be defined twice, which is a linking error.

**Incomplete Python emulation.**  String libraries can actually be quite complicated.  For example, which characters are considered whitespace?  [Traditionally](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/isspace.3.html), the whitespace characters are <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Newline</kbd>, <kbd>Vertical tab</kbd>, <kbd>Form feed</kbd>, <kbd>Carriage return</kbd>, and <kbd>Space</kbd>, but [Unicode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) defines many more whitespace characters, so the answer may vary by locale.  Should `len()` count bytes, or should it count Unicode characters, assuming that its argument is a string encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)?  If your library is inspired by Python, people may have an expectation that it behaves like Python.

**Memory handling.**  Your `rstrip()` function clobbers the input string.  C programmers sometimes tolerate such behaviour, if it's documented.  However, the fact that your `rstrip()` returns a `char *` rather than `void` suggests that it returns the stripped string as a copy, rather than modifying the original.  On the other hand, your `slice()` function returns a copy and leaves the original unmolested.  In short, your library has no consistent memory-management policy, which is essential for any cohesive C library.  As a result, anyone who uses it is likely to get segfaults and/or memory leaks.

**Stray pointer dereference in len().**  Your `len()` function has a statement `*string++;` that should be just `string++;`.  By the way, if you had written `(*string)++;` instead, you would have implemented a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) shifting by 1.

**You could use C library functions.**  Your `len()` is just `strlen()` (but returning a signed rather than unsigned int).  Your `lstrip()` could use `strspn()` or `isspace()`.  In short, get familiar with the C library's built-in functions before you write your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variant on these functions.  I've passed in a character set, `cset`, that is to be stripped instead of assuming we are stripping just spaces or using `isspace`. So you might pass in

```
" \t\n\r"
```

as `cset`, for example.

```
size_t lstrip(char * restrict s, const char * restrict cset)
{
    const char *t = s + strspn(s, cset);
    size_t len = strlen(t);

    if (s != t) {
        memmove(s, t, len + 1); // +1 to capture the \0
    }
    return len;
}
```

Here is `rstrip`

```
size_t rstrip(char * restrict s, const char * restrict cset)
{
    char *end = s + strlen(s);

    while (end > s && strchr(cset, *end)) {
        --end;
    }
    end[1] = '\0';
    return (size_t) (end - s);
}
```

These functions are reasonably efficient.

Implementing `slice` is much more complicated if you want to emulate Python well because Python (as far as I remember) allows negative values in start/end so that you can slice relative to the end rather than the start.  Your version doesn't handle such things.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve time-efficiency for certain operations would be to package the string in a struct. If you make the `char*` the first member, then the struct can be cast to a `char*` and used normally. But it lets you stash a length member and avoid recalculating.

```
struct mystr {
    char *ptr;
    size_t len;
};
```